# How do installers bypass permissions on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions

I noticed that while using `pip` to install packages globally, the install failed with an insufficient permission error. When running `pip` as administrator, the problem was fixed and `pip` was able to write to my `Program Files` directory. The same behavior occurs when editing text files in `Program Files` -- it only works if I run the text editor as administrator.

However, far as I know, I have never run any installer programs as administrator, yet they all wrote to my `Program Files` directory without any kind of prompt. What allows these installers to bypass the security check?

(I do have UAC disabled, but if that's the cause then why can't `pip` and other normal programs like text editors write to the `Program Files` directory?)

Comment: This is  security feature. Permissions on system folders doesn't allow modify it without elevated permissions. If you turn UAC back on, then installers will pop up a confirmation windows too. M$ assumes if file name containing word `Setup` then it should run as administrator.

Comment: moving slider down, no longer disables UAC since win8, because the store apps require an activated UAC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the UAC slider is all the way down, programs that ask for elevation will automatically be approved. That's distinct from all programs being elevated all the time (which is effectively what you get if you [completely disable UAC](https://superuser.com/a/83678/380318), which would break things).

Programs can specify their elevation behavior in their [manifest](https://superuser.com/a/1028723/380318). Most programs run `asInvoker`, at the same level as the calling process. Some, like the Registry Editor and MMC, ask to be run with the `highestAvailable` permissions, so with UAC on, admins would get an elevation prompt but normal users wouldn't. Others, like most setup programs, are completely useless without elevation and therefore `requireAdministrator`. That's why setup programs are automatically elevating for you. Evidently, `pip` is not manifested as requiring elevation. "You have not because you ask not."

Bonus demonstration: one way to start an elevated program from the command line is PowerShell's `Start-Process` with `-Verb runas`, like this:

```
Start-Process cmd -Verb runas
```

With UAC on, running that will give you an elevation prompt for the command prompt. With UAC lowered to the minimum allowed by the UI, you get an elevated command prompt with no UAC dialog. (You can see the difference in the command window's title bar.) Had the `-Verb runas` been left off, you would have just got a normal command prompt.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that there was a difference between "all the way down" and "completely off" (IIRC they were the same on Win7). Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewSun I explained you why this is a diff in my comment